# Weight different misclassifications differently keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want my model to increase the loss for a false positive prediction when training by creating a custom loss function.
The class_weight parameter in model.fit() does not work for this issue. The class_weight is already set to { 0: 1, 1:23 } as I have skewed training data where there are 23 times as many non-true labels as there are true labels.

I am not too experienced when working with the keras backend. I have mostly worked with the functional model.

What I want to create is:

```
def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    #where y_true == 0 and y_pred == 1:
    #   weight this loss and make it 50 times larger
    #return loss
```

I can do simple stuff with the tensors such as getting the mean squared error but I have no idea how to do logical stuff.
I have tried to do some hacky solution which doesnt work and feels totally wrong:

```
def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    false_positive_weight = 50        
    thresh = 0.5
    y_pred_true = K.greater_equal(thresh,y_pred)
    y_not_true = K.less_equal(thresh,y_true)
    false_positive_tensor = K.equal(y_pred_true,y_not_true)

    loss_weights = K.ones_like(y_pred) + false_positive_weight*false_positive_tensor

    return K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)*loss_weights
```

I am using python 3 with keras 2 and tensorflow as backend.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're almost there...

```
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy

def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    false_positive_weight = 50        
    thresh = 0.5
    y_pred_true = K.greater_equal(thresh,y_pred)
    y_not_true = K.less_equal(thresh,y_true)
    false_positive_tensor = K.equal(y_pred_true,y_not_true)


    #changing from here

    #first let's transform the bool tensor in numbers - maybe you need float64 depending on your configuration
    false_positive_tensor = K.cast(false_positive_tensor,'float32') 

    #and let's create it's complement (the non false positives)
    complement = 1 - false_positive_tensor

    #now we're going to separate two groups
    falsePosGroupTrue = y_true * false_positive_tensor
    falsePosGroupPred = y_pred * false_positive_tensor

    nonFalseGroupTrue = y_true * complement
    nonFalseGroupPred = y_pred * complement


    #let's calculate one crossentropy loss for each group
    #(directly from the keras loss functions imported above)
    falsePosLoss = binary_crossentropy(falsePosGroupTrue,falsePosGroupPred)
    nonFalseLoss = binary_crossentropy(nonFalseGroupTrue,nonFalseGroupPred)

    #return them weighted:
    return (false_positive_weight*falsePosLoss) + nonFalseLoss
```

Comment: Notice that this weight here is applied to the predict value, not to the loss, so there may be a correction if you want it in the loss value.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick answer. The problem with applying the weight to the predictions is that K.binary_crossentropy clips the values of y_pred to EPSILON, 1 - EPSILON and therefore removes the adjustments made here. I would instead like to multiply the loss values returned by K.binary_crossentropy corresponding to a false positive by a certain weight. Any idea how that could be done?

Comment: `weighted_falses = (false_positive_weight-1)*false_positive_tensor`                                                                                    This line failes to compile in model.compile(). It says that it expected bool but got int

Comment: I updated the code, and this time I tested it properly. I also changed it to apply the weight only at the end.